# which antivirus best for window 10 on hp laptops?

Tags: antivirus, account-security

which antivirus best for window 10 for security and virus protection specially for hp laptops.

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic here. You might try [softwarerecs.se]. Or you might check test sites like [av-test](https://www.av-test.org/) or [av-comparatives](https://www.av-comparatives.org/).

Answer (score 1):

We don't recommend products here, but some advice to help you choose:

- The built-in AV that comes with your computer is OK, not great, but a) better than nothing and b) sufficient as part of a holistic approach to the security of your laptop. See for example the NCSC advice at  https://www.ncsc.gov.uk/guidance/eud-security-guidance-windows-10-1709.
- The big-name vendors all do a decent job.
- The free versions from the big-name vendors also do a decent job, because they're the same product. The difference between free and paid is not that the free is less able to detect viruses; it's that the paid version includes optional extra features and the free version nags you to upgrade.
- You might want to avoid ones from countries with the sort of government you can imagine leaning on their local anti-virus vendors to do naughty things, but an equally valid approach is to say that all governments are likely to do that so what difference does it make?